# firefox browser settings to avoid appearance of menu bar or task bar in full screen when pointing mouse on the top of the screen

Tags: firefox, fullscreenchange

I am using firefox 3.0 in rhel6.2.Wwhen I press F11, the fullscreen mode appears, but if the mouse pointer goes to the top of the screen at fulscreen mode then the task bar appears. I want to avoid the appearance of this bar. I have searched the net but got the answers how to show them in full screen.
Please suggest me the settings I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile folder>/chrome/` (check in `profiles.ini` which profile you are using), and put this piece of code in `userChrome.css` (create one if it doesn't exist)

```
/* only needed once */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#fullscr-toggler { display:none!important; }
```

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942904

Comment: I'm running Firefox `106.0.3`; I added this, but it didn't work. I know `userChrome.css` is being found, and is being applied (because other settings in `userChrome.css` take effect). Despite this, the address bar *still* pops up whenever I move the mouse to the top of the screen. This is infuriating and makes it Jupyter lab near impossible to use in full screen mode. Can I confirm that this is *supposed* to prevent the address bar from appearing when the mouse is moved to the top of the screen in full-screen mode?

Comment: @MRule try this instead:
```
#navigator-toolbox[inFullscreen="true"] {
  margin-top: -99px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Open Firefox and type `about:config` in the addressbar and press Enter. It'll confirm, click on I'll be careful, I promise! button.

Now type autohide in the Filter box and look for following boolean key:

```
browser.fullscreen.autohide
```

The entry "browser.fullscreen.autohide" would be set to true. Double-click on it and change its value to **false**.

Comment: I believe OP wants the task bar to not appear, and not to always appear.

Comment: @Ankur Tiwari, Thank you for ur help but this is making the task bar appear always in fullscreen mode, but I wanted the opposite of this. Well its solved now